# DynamoDB/Boto3 - Invalid type for parameter ExpressionAttributeValues, type NULL

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

So I have an AWS database that has 4 column attributes:

1. id (primary partition key)
2. location (latitude coordinates as String)
3. location2 (longitude coordinates as String)
4. user location (location of a user as String, e.g "New York, USA"

Only some items in the database have `location` and `location2` filled in and I want to fill the items with empty `location` and `location2`, (rather the non existent), ones.

I am doing this by scanning the database, taking the `user location` and converting it into latitude and longitude coordinates, and so forth.

I then check in the `ConditionExpression` if `location2` exists, (I made a mistake and in some items there is `location` but not `location2`) and I check if the converted coordinates are correct by seeing if they are of type `None`/`NULL`. IF the conditions are met, then it should update and thus filling the empty slots in the database.

Here is my function:

```
def scan()
 response = client.scan(
    TableName=TABLE_NAME,
    )

 geolocator = GoogleV3()
 sleep(1.1)
 non_value = None

 for i in response['Items']:
     idNr = i['id']['N']
     try:
         userLocation = i['user location']['S']
         coordinates = geolocator.geocode(userLocation, timeout=10)
         sleep(1.1)
         latitude = coordinates.latitude
         sleep(1.1)
         longitude = coordinates.longitude
         sleep(1.1)
         print "User Location succesfully made into coordinates"

         if latitude and longitude:
             print latitude, longitude
         response = client.update_item(
             Key={'id': {'N': str(idNr)}},
             TableName=TABLE_NAME,
             ExpressionAttributeNames={"#c":"location"},
             UpdateExpression='SET #c = :lati, location2 = :longi, #n = :null',
             ConditionExpression="attribute_not_exists(location2) OR attribute_type(userLoca, #n) OR attribute_type(lati, #n) OR attribute_type(longi, #n)",
             ExpressionAttributeValues={
                     ':lati': {'S': str(latitude)},
                     ':longi': {'S': str(longitude)},
                     ':userLoca': {'S': userLocation},
                     ':null': {'NULL': non_value}
                     },
             ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
             )
     except ClientError as e:
         if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "ConditionalCheckFailedException":
             print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
         else:
             raise
```

So according to the documentation I am supposed to be able to use the function `attribute_type(path, type)`as mentioned here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html

But I keep getting:

`Invalid type for parameter ExpressionAttributeValues.:null.NULL, value: None, type: <type 'NoneType'>, valid types: <type 'bool'>`

The documentation clearly says that I can use `NULL` as a type in the function, I also correctly specified the `ExpressionAttributeValues` according to the specs! Have no idea on what is wrong...

Please, Gods of Stack, you are my only hope..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As weird as it sounds, the NULL value is not None, it has to be true (funny enough, it can't be false, tried it), because The NULL type in dynamodb accepts only this value.

So change your code to:

`non_value=True`

and it should work.

Based on [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html)